# Windows 7 Turkish language pack problem

Tags: windows-7, language-pack

I have Windows 7 Ultimate RTM (7600) installed on my laptop. I installed the Turkish language pack from Windows Update but some texts like "Welcome" "Shutting Down" and "Starting Windows" are still in English, but the others are translated into Turkish correctly. Did anyone face with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Language packs are, by default, enabled on a per-user basis. Your Turkish pack is probably enabled just for your user at the moment.

Navigate to:

- Control Panel
- Clock, Language, and Region
- Region And Language
- Administrative (Tab)
- Copy Settings (Button)

(If your Control Panel is in Classic View, follow the following:)

- Control Panel
- Region And Language
- Administrative (Tab)
- Copy Settings (Button)

Check the two check boxes at the bottom of the window displayed:

- Welcome screen and system accounts
- New user accounts (Optional, check if you want new users to be Turkish by default)

and reboot your system once instructed. This should apply your language pack to the system accounts and the text during boot up and welcome screen will be localized.

Comment: You are right! But it's different on Windows 7. Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Administrative Tab -> Copy Settings.

Comment: **@A Dwarf:** What you just enumerated is the Control Panel in Classic View... Category view is what I enumerated.

Comment: Yes mate it's my solution at last :)
I don't know how I overlooked it but it's fully (%100) Turkish now including all welcome messages etc...Thanx very much...

Answer (score 1):

Some language packs are what is known as **Partially Localized Language Packs**. They don't contain a 100% localization of all resources, although they do contain all the resources. The non localized resources are usually in the English language. See, [Understanding Language Packs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766472%28WS.10%29.aspx)

I'm unsure as to how and when do Partially Localized MUI Packs evolve into fully localized ones. Being the case Windows does get distributed in Turkey fully localized, I'm sure it is simply a matter of time until the folks at Redmond update the Turkish MUI. (Please remember: **Windows 7 is still not officially out**)

FYI, just a few months ago, the Portuguese Pack was also only partially localized. From what I can gather with a quick inspection I did recently, the pack I downloaded through my MSDN subscription last week is already 100% localized.

Comment: As I told,on my previous install,it was fully %100 translated into Turkish.When you look at the list of language packs on MS Update of Windows 7 you can see all local language packs in there.So no solutions yet...